# Changing control themes in AvaloniaUI based on OS theme

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I have several custom controls with custom styles in avalonia 11.0.5. How can i adjust styles to automatically change appearance according to OS Dark or Light theme

I fount solution, based on :

```xml
<Application xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="YourNamespace.App">
    <Application.Styles>
        <StyleInclude Source="LightTheme.axaml" />
        <StyleInclude Source="DarkTheme.axaml" />
    </Application.Styles>
</Application>

<!-- LightTheme.axaml -->
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style Selector="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
    </Style>
</Styles>

<!-- DarkTheme.axaml -->
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style Selector="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
    </Style>
</Styles>

<Button Content="Click me" Classes="Button" />
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply theme conditional `ResourceDictionaries` under the `ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries` element.  With this strategy you will add `SolidColorBrush` to your ResourceDictionary and reference them by Key as DynamicResources.  Then your Button only needs one style.

```xml
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceInclude Source='avares://Path.To/LightTheme.axaml'/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>

      <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceInclude Source='avares://Path.To/DarkTheme.axaml'/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

You don't have to used merged dictionaries, you can put the SolidColorBrushes directly in the Light and Dark dictionaries above, but if you end up with a lot of them, it gets long and hard to read your App.axaml.

LightTheme.axaml:

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Background" Color="LightGray"/>
```

DarkTheme.axaml:

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Background" Color="DarkGray"/>
```

```xml
<Button Content="Click me" Classes="Button" Background="{DynamicResource Button.Background}"/>
```